# Specifying trigger conditions to reduce API calls as opposed to using a condition in the flow itself

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am using an automated flow on a SharePoint list with the "item created or modified" trigger. The flow will trigger a logic app when certain conditions are met. I've tested two different solutions:

**Using a condition in the flow**
[image]
This is the simplest solution and it works well. However this means that the flow is executed even if the parameters are not included.

**Using trigger conditions**

[image]

This also works well, and the logic app is not run unless the conditions are met.

Does the approach with trigger conditions reduce API calls count as opposed to: `When modified > Check values > Do or Don't do stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the workflow doesn't get triggered, I believe the polling request made by trigger is still billed as mentioned in the [pricing model & usage metering doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#triggers).

But even with that, you will reduce the action calls made for checking the conditions within your logic app and have a clean workflow run history.

Comment: One downside compared to having the logic within the flow is that the latter will inform you of failed runs in the history.